# Should I use "don't" or "didn't" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> She refused meeting me, ignored my calls, and did her best so we don't/didn't
>   cross paths at school.

I'm not sure whether I should use *don't* or *didn't* in the sentence above.

Comment: I think your sentence should be rephrased. "We cross paths" sounds not quite correct to me.  See 'cross somebody's path' http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cross+path. Maybe [...] *best so that I could not cross her path.*

Comment: @Humbulani: You're mistaken - *"We don't [often] cross paths"* is a perfectly natural current usage, but *"I don't [often] cross **her path**"* isn't at all idiomatic.

Comment: I'd use wouldn't instead of don't/didn't, removing the contractions: did her best so we do not cross paths/did not cross paths, would not follows the past tense of refused, ignored, and did, and doesn't reuse 'did'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really just depends on the relationship between "narrative time" (that you're *writing/speaking **about***), and "utterance time" (when the statement is actually ***made***).

That's to say, if it's relevant *now* (at time of speaking) that you *still* don't cross paths, present tense ***don't*** is appropriate. But if you're reminiscing (perhaps decades later) about your schooldays, say, then it's all in the past - so you'd use ***didn't***.

Not directly relevant, but idiomatically, *"She refused meeting me"* is extremely unlikely/ungainly here. It would normally be *"She refused **to meet** me"*.

Comment: I would argue (as I did in my answer) that the use of the past tense throughout means you are talking about the past. Plus "She **did** her best so we **don't** cross paths" just sounds wrong to my native ear. The mismatched tenses are just jarring.

Comment: @trlkly: I can't see why a *native* speaker should have a problem with using past tense to report something that happened, but present tense for the result *if that result is still true and relevant*. Temporally speaking, it's no different to *"I **am crying** (now) because he **hit** me (then)"* - for which *"I cry because he hits me"* just sounds like a typical nns error caused by trying to "regularise" the tense.

Comment: And I don't understand how a native speaker can't immediately tell that it's wrong. That's why I assumed you weren't one. Your example that sounds okay is constructed completely differently. It uses present progressive, which is what you use for an action that is continuing. It also is constructed where the present comes first, which is far more normal. The structure of the OP's sentence is such that is it primarily cast in the past tense. If it continued into the present, the sentence would be "She does her best so that we don't cross paths." Both parts would continue to the present.

Comment: "Doing her best" is a continual action. If it's set in the past tense, it means it has been completed.

Comment: @trlkly: I'd be inclined to agree with you (at least that past tense ***didn't*** is more *likely*, not that present tense is "incorrect") if OP's example had included *"doing her best"*. Because that would set the narrative time so firmly in the past that an allusion to "time of utterance" would be jarring. But it's actually *"did her best"* anyway, and I pointed out in my answer that the "quasi-continuous" *"refused meeting"* is unlikely in the extreme. If you think continuous makes a difference, how about *"I saw him yesterday so I don't have to see him tomorrow"*.

Comment: No, what's giving me trouble is that you are saying it can be an ongoing thing, but the entire sentence is cast in the past. She refused meeting me. She didn't take my calls. Not she is refusing to meet me and she isn't taking my calls. It's all in the past. And she did her best. She is not still doing her best. It's past tense. The action is completed. So what she did her best to do must also be in the past. Everything about the sentence is in the past. It makes no sense for it to continue to the present.

Comment: I would also say you can't say "She is doing her best so that we didn't cross paths." That's also wrong. She is currently doing her best, but that's somehow affecting the past. She can't currently do something to prevent us from crossing paths in the past.

Comment: I guess we'll just have to agree to differ. So far as I'm concerned, if she and the speaker are both still at the school, and their paths ***still don't*** cross because of her earlier efforts to make sure they don't, that final "result" is still applicable, and present tense is appropriate.

Comment: But the other two actions aren't continuing? She is no longer refusing to meet me and no longer ignoring my calls, but she is still intentionally not crossing paths with me? Even if I allow that your present tense is possible, I cannot see how it's likely.

Comment: Actually, I'm taking it back. Someone on another forum (I asked because I couldn't believe you were right) suggested a better answer. It needs to be in the subjunctive. I'm adding a new answer (so that I don't keep the upvote from the old answer.)

Comment: I don't see what the argument is here. How different is FumbleFinger's suggested scenario from "Our father sacrificed himself so that we don't go hungry" speaking of the present, or "... so that we wouldn't go hungry" keeping it in the past? It sounds perfectly "native" to me?

Comment: @CocoPop: *... and Uncle FumbleFingers bought us shoes so we **didn't** have to walk to school barefoot* (perfectly valid "true" past as opposed to "hypothetical future in the past" ***wouldn't** have to*).  It is a somewhat bizarre situation here. Of seven answers, two just *aren't* ("answers" at all), but all the others apart from mine assert that one or both of ***don't/didn't*** are actually "wrong" in some way. Where on earth do people get these ideas from?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just cast it differently

> She refused to meet me, ignored my calls, and did her best to avoid us crossing paths at school.

Comment: I'd go further and get rid of "us." Everything else is about me. So I'd say "She refused to meet me, ignored my calls, and did her best to avoid crossing paths with me at school."

Answer (score 1):

It should be "didn't". The sentence up to this point has been in the past tense, so it wouldn't make sense to switch to present tense for this one verb.
I would also change "did her best so we didn't cross paths" to **"went out of her way to make sure we didn't cross paths"**

Answer (score 1):

While I would prefer "didn't" to "don't" in this situation, I don't think either one is correct. The subordinating conjunction "so" calls out for the subjunctive. So the correct word would be "wouldn't."

> She refused to meet me, ignored my calls, and did her best so we wouldn't cross paths.

There are, of course, other ways to cast the sentence. Someone I talked to suggested that "did her best to" is more idiomatic, so the sentence becomes

> She refused to meet me, ignored my calls, and did her best to ensure we wouldn't cross paths.

Either way, "wouldn't" is the better word choice.

Comment: In *"If I were you, I would do such-and-such"*, it's ***were*** that's in the subjunctive, not ***would***. Your rewording with auxiliary + infinitive *(would/should+cross)* is the [*more common in American English*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-subjunctive.htm) way of *avoiding* the subjunctive *"...so [that] we not cross paths"*